# Fetch html content of child tag inside li

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a list like:

```
<ol id="id1">
<li><strong>aaa</strong><em>bbb<br />ccc</em></li>
<li><strong>111</strong><em>222<br />333</em></li>
</ol>
```

How do I get the html content of `<em>` tag within each `<li>` ?

I tried using jQuery's `.html()` method but is behaving inconsistently on android html5 app I'm trying to make. Android 5.1 above are able to read that well, but android 4.4.2 device doesn't doesn't display anything.

Is there an alternate way of getting html please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var liElements = document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<liElements.length;i++){
    alert(liElements[i].getElementsByTagName("em")[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: You may want to try this native JS example. If jQuery isn't working properly on Android, then having to fall back to the native JS language is probably what you'll need to try to do next. Maybe this will work out better in https://www.browserstack.com than jQuery does.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').each(function(){
   alert($(this).find('em').html());
});
```

or

```
$('li em').each(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Using innerHTML:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    alert(items[i].getElementsByTagName("em")[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, the results are inconsistent with .html() function. Any other alternates like innerhtml function?

Answer (score 0):

You could get all *em* elements like this and then iterate over them.

```
$(function(){
  $("ol li > em").each(function(index, element){
    var em = $(element).html();
    alert(em);
  });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
  $("ol li > em").each(function(index, element){
    var em = $(element).html();
    alert(em);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="id1">
<li><strong>aaa</strong><em>bbb<br />ccc</em></li>
<li><strong>111</strong><em>222<br />333</em></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you what you are looking for:

```
var insideEM = $("li").children("em").html();
```

Answer will be : `222<br />333`

Answer (score 0):

This is the most human aproach i think for vanilla js of course:

```js
var $list = document.querySelectorAll("#id1 li em");
document.write("<br />");

for (i = 0; i < $list.length; i++) {
   document.write((i+1) + " match: <br />");
  
   document.write($list[i].innerHTML);
  
   document.write("<br />");
}
```

```html
<ol id="id1">
<li><strong>aaa</strong><em>bbb<br />ccc</em></li>
<li><strong>111</strong><em>222<br />333</em></li>
</ol>
```